# After upgrade to Fedora 32 my apps are not searchable in gnome

Tags: fedora, gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell

After upgrading F31 to latest Fedora32 I am unable to use gnome UI to start apps. When I try to search the app by name - it says "Searching" and that's it. No apps come up. For example I have **chrome** installed, but I can't find it.

If I try to use "Show applications" icon from the sidebar, gnome-shell crashes

- **GNOME Shell** 3.36.2
- **Kernal**: 5.6.10-300.fc32.x86_64

[image]

### Any ideas?

Comment: Did you restart? I've upgraded to F32 only issue Ive got - broken gnome shell shotcut.

Comment: Also check on gnome bugtracker

Comment: Yes I already reported to bugtracker. And of course did several rounds of **dnf update** and restarts. That didn't help.

Comment: If you create a new _testlogin_ account, are the symptoms the same?